# Entity Framework - Saving changes made to a detached entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entities

Say changes have been made to a detached entity in EF 4. If we want to save theses changes when we re-attached the entity, is it possible to do this with ApplyCurrentValues without querying the DB to get the original entity?  I don't think so, but I'd like somebody to confirm that.

```
using (var ctx = new BAEntities())   
{
var firstCust = (from c in ctx.Contacts select c).First();
Console.WriteLine(firstCust.FirstName);
ctx.Contacts.Detach(firstCust);

firstCust.FirstName = "Modified Value";
ctx.Contacts.Attach(firstCust);
ctx.ApplyCurrentValues("Contacts", firstCust);//Does not work

//ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(firstCust, EntityState.Modified); //Works with that line
            ctx.SaveChanges( );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm your guess. It doesn't work this way.

When you call `Attach` with an entity as parameter EF adds the entity to the context in state `Unchanged`. Basically you are telling EF with `Attach` that all property values the entity has at that time represent the current values in the database.

`ApplyCurrentValues` is kind of an "automapper" that just copies the property values of the object you pass into `ApplyCurrentValues` to the attached entity that has the same key. This copy happens based on the property name.

If a property value of the attached entity is different to the property value of the object you pass into `ApplyCurrentValues` EF marks the property as `Modified`. If not the state stays `Unchanged`. Obviously with your procedure all property states will stay unchanged and nothing gets written to the database.

In theory you could do crazy stuff to make it work like:

```
firstCust.FirstName = "Modified Value";
var dummyCust = new Contact { FirstName = "UnlikelyNameThatWillNeverOccur" };
ctx.Contacts.Attach(dummyCust);
ctx.ApplyCurrentValues("Contacts", firstCust);
```

Here the `FirstName` property would be marked as `Modified`. But you had to do this for every property and the result will be the same as setting the state of the whole entity to `Modified` as you did in the commented code line.

You can by the way set a single property to `Modified`:

```
ctx.Contacts.Attach(firstCust);
ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(firstCust)
    .SetModifiedProperty("FirstName");
```

This will send an UPDATE statement to the database that only sets the `FirstName` column value (while setting the state of the whole entity to `Modified` will create an UPDATE statement that sets *all* column values to the current property values).